# Basic algebra for Excel function

Tags: excel, math, logic

I am working in an Excel workbook where a monetary value is displayed. This amount is the difference between two constants, and represents a shortfall in a customer's payout, for which we need to compensate customers.

I need to work out the required compensation amount from this.

Customers are entitled to some compensation only if their shortfall > £1.00.  We only compensate them up to that level (shortfall - £1). We have a minimum payment amount of £0.50.

So, to calculate the compensation required, I think I need to apply the following logic to the shortfall number :-

Shortfall is greater than £1
AND
Shortfall minus £1 is GREATER THAN than 50p

This is two steps and I think there is an easier, cleaner way.

I think this could be described as y = x - 1 > 0.5

I would have to use an AND function to do this, but I am sure there is a simpler way to describe this using one simpler function.

I have just completely unable to get my head around it though.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you payout the whole shortfall? In which case, shortfall over £1.00 means a payout of >50p straight away

Comment: No, we do not pay out all shortfall. People only qualify for compensation at all if the shortfall > £1, and we only pay compensation up to 'shortfall - £1'. The minmum amount we will then pay out is 50p. So someone whose shortfall is £1.20 would not get anthing because although the shortfall > £1, the award we would have to pay would be £0.20, and therefore below the minimum award threshold.

Answer (score 1):

Shortfall is greater than £1 AND Shortfall minus £1 is GREATER THAN than 50p  equates to shortfall must be greater than £1.50

Comment: Yes, but as the minimum compensation amount is 50p, if I calculate this as compensation = shortfall - £1.50, I will still end up with compensation amounts less than 50p... e.g. where shortfall is £1.51, £1.52, etc.

Comment: No you use Shortfall > 1.5 as the if condition to the calculation shortfall - 1 So (assume Shortfall in A1)  =IF(A1>1.5,A1-1,0)